# How to fill objects with many different member types in a clever way, polymorphically?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

Is there an OO pattern to fill objects with lots of data, with this data being usually different within each object, polymorphically?
[edited] The issue here is that in another part of the code I will have a pointer to the base class and I want to fill the data of the concrete objects pointed by this base class.

- My first idea was to create a base class with pure virtual methods. So each concrete object would implement how its data is filled. However, as the code evolved I noticed that the base class grown too much only to store dozens of pure abstracts methods, and that concrete classes overwritten a lot of unnecessary methods that were only useful in its siblings.

**Example:**

```
public Filler
{
     virtual void fill_struct1(struct myStruct1) = 0;
     virtual void fill_struct2(struct myStruct2) = 0;
     // I will need more methods to give the derivate objects the capacity of
     // filling its data members polymorphically.
}

class A: public Filler
{
     void fill_struct1(struct myStruct1);
     void fill_struct2(struct myStruct2);
     // There can be more overwritten methods.
     struct myStruct1 member_1;
     struct myStruct2 member_2;
     struct myStruct3 member_3;
     // There can be more members of different types.
}

class B: public Filler
{
     void fill_struct1(struct myStruct1);
     void fill_struct2(struct myStruct2);
     void fill_struct4(struct myStruct4);
     // There can be more overwritten methods.
     struct myStruct1 member_1;
     struct myStruct2 member_2;
     struct myStruct4 member_3;
     // There can be more members of different types. But sometimes the members can be equal one used in a sibling.
}
```

Comment: You might want to delete the second  definition of `class A` in the snippet.

Comment: As a first step, if it's normal for derived types to not want to override all of the base type's `virtual` members, don't make then pure virtual.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Well, as long as you are fine with those derived types also being abstract, I don't see the issue...

Comment: @MaxLanghof I suspect that it would be a problem for the derived types to be abstract, since it seems like OP wants to instantiate them. Otherwise he/she wouldn't complain *"that concrete classes overwritten a lot of unnecessary methods that were only useful in its siblings."*

Comment: Speaking of abstraction, this question is awfully vague. If some child classes lack a `MyStruct3` member, then why do you want a `fill_struct3()` method? Why not just have one abstract `fill_all_members()` method? What, conceptually, do you intend these methods to do? *What problem are you actually trying to solve?*

Comment: Two types can be polymorphic if they have the same operations but do different things with them.  In your case, you have a bunch of types with different operations.  These types are not polymorphic, and you seem to want to force them to be.  There isn't any information in your question asto *why* you want them to be polymorphic; your design has a bad code smell.  Please step back and look at the problem a level higher.

Comment: @ Beta. In another part of the code I have a pointer to the base class and I want to fill the concrete objects polymorphically. That is the issue.

Comment: @ Yakk - Adam Nevraumont. Do you have an advice of how to better design this type of code?

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are trying to do. If all descendants of Base need to fill member1, then presumably all of them have member1, and it should already be in Base. If some descendants don't have member1 and don't need to fill it, then fill_member1 should not be in Base.

Comment: Question is not clear but it sounds like composite pattern might be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

One way to beat some redundancy could be to use template methods:

```
template<class T>
void fill_struct1(T& obj)
{
  obj.member_1 = ...;
}
```

This can be called on any object that has a `member_1` (with type `myStruct1`, presumably). If all your `fill_struct1` methods do the exact same thing, this may be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

Try to separate concerns here:

- Setting up instances of `A` or related classes should be done in the constructor. If you have too many parameters to be passed into the constructor, group them in a struct.
- If setting up different instances requires similar code snippets, put these in a free function
- If the logic behind setting up these instances is *very* complicated, look out for the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). This involves classes in a different hierarchy, opposed to what your current approach suggests.
- Base classes and derived classes can have different member variables, it's fine to separate them as much as possible. Share state between derived classes via protected member variables in the base class only when necessary.

Another issue is quite orthogonal to this first point:

- The concrete type of your subclasses are known when instantiating them: simply invoke the constructor
- The concrete type shall be hidden. You instantiate via a clone-like method ([virtual constructor idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor), [prototype pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern)).